# Open links from excel one by one to Internet Explorer

Tags: excel, internet-explorer, vba

I have more than 100 links in Excel and I want to open them in Internet Explorer one by one. The computer assigned to me is somewhat slow that is why the links need to be opened in just one tab of Internet Explorer.

I want to:

1.Copy link from A1, paste it to Internet Explorer.

2.Wait until the page is fully loaded.

3.Copy link from A2, paste it to Internet Explorer (same tab, not opening a 
    new tab).

4.Wait until the page is fully loaded.

5.Repeat steps until the last cell of "A" with links.

In the code below, I can navigate the link from A1. How can you loop it that it will navigate from cell 1 to cell X.

```
Sub OpenInAnotherBrowser()
Dim iePath As String
Dim browser As String
Dim URL As String

iePath = "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"

If Dir(iePath) = "" Then pathie = "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"

URL = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value

If Dir(iePath) = "" Then
    If MsgBox("IE Not Found, Open with default browser?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        Application.FollowHyperlink URL
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If

Shell """" & iePath & """" & URL, vbHide

End Sub
```

Comment: Déjà vu?  I'm sure I saw this exact same question within the last week or so.

Comment: I edited the code. Somewhat same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code loops through the links in column A in sheet1. Look out for broken links and things like that as there are no check for those things in this code.

```
Sub Main()

Dim IE As Object
Dim rngURL As Range
Dim rng As Range

' not perfect, but it is a quick way to keep VBA from looping through 1000000+ rows without using a bunch of ifs....
Set rngURL = Intersect(Sheet1.UsedRange, Sheet1.Columns("A"))

Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

IE.Visible = True

For Each rng In rngURL

    rng.Select

    If Trim(rng.Value) <> "" Then

        IE.Navigate Trim(rng.Value)

        Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Loop

        MsgBox IE.LocationURL ' This is just to slow things down a little bit

    End If

Next rng

IE.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: Lungdren. there is an error here: IE.Navigate Trim(rng.Value)